# Cannot add a Signing Certificate in Outlook due to missing 'More choices' option

Tags: microsoft-outlook, certificate

I discovered that there is something wrong with my AVG certificate for Outlook 2019. I tried [this](https://support.avg.com/supportarticleview?l=en&urlName=troubleshoot-invalid-avg-antivirus-email-certificate&supportType=home) solution from AVG, but I do not have the 'More choices' option at step 8 of the Outlook solution.

For if the link dies, here are the steps:

> **Export Email Shield certificate**
>
> 1. Open AVG AntiVirus and go to ☰ Menu ▸ Settings.
> 2. Click the Search icon in the top-right corner.
> 3. Type geek:area into the text box, and select AVG Geek from the search results.
> 4. Scroll to the Email Shield section. Ensure the box next to Scan SSL connections is ticked, then click Perform next to Export
>    certificate.
> 5. Select a location to save the exported Email Shield certificate (for example, your Windows Desktop) and click Save.
> 6. Click OK in the AVG Information dialog.
> 7. Import the Email Shield certificate into your email client.
>
> **Import Email Shield certificate**
>
> 1. In Microsoft Outlook, click the File tab.
> 2. Select Options in the bottom-left corner of the screen.
> 3. Click Trust Center.
> 4. Select Trust Center Settings.
> 5. Click Email Security.
> 6. Click Settings....
> 7. Next to Signing Certificate, select Choose....
> 8. Click More choices, then select the certificate you want to use.  **<-- I don't see this!**
> 9. Click OK to save your changes.

Does somebody know how I can get the More choices option or an alternative way of how to install this *.der certificate?

I tried to run Outlook as Administrator, but no success.

BTW There was no Default Settings set up, but when I added a new one, it didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Those instructions make no sense. As the same page says, the certificate you export isn't even a S/MIME user certificate – it's a root CA certificate (and is used for issuing TLS server certificates) – so it wouldn't show up in that list even if you could import certificates there.

(AVG "Mail Shield" uses TLS interception, so instead of the server's real TLS certificate you always see a fake one issued by the local AVG scanner.)

As Outlook uses the global TLS certificate store from Windows, you need to import the AVG custom root through `certmgr.msc` to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities", although it's likely that AVG has already installed it there for HTTPS scanning.